# How to debug an Android program on a real device using Eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging, device

I have never used debugging on real Android devices yet. I read the manual at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html  for debugging.

I downloaded the driver for Acere130 Android 2.1 to test on it. Now I am not getting any devices when I use command on adb, using `adb devices`.  No real device is there. Only when I run the emulator does it show the emulator virtual device. How can I move forward? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed adb driver.

Comment: And you can see your phone when you connect it with your computer? In the DDMS tool.

Comment: yes.. Exactly .. what am i not getting is this only..  In DDMS tool , my device is not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into the developer settings menu on the phone and enable USB debugging.

Comment: i have already done that .. but i am not getting the device attached  on eclipse on going to DDMS->Devices

Comment: is the device being recognised by windows in device manager? You should be able to see an Android Composite ADB Interface listed.

Comment: yes it is recognized well in device manager. Yes i am seeing this Composite ADB interface listed.

Comment: Seems your phone drivers are not helping you. I also have the same problem but it fixed when I installed my phone drivers.

Comment: Yes mcnicholls , i also doubt for the same, The Usb driver i have installed is for ACer e130 from acer website. So what may be the next approach.

Comment: have you tried rebooting your machine? Failing that have you tried uninstalling and then reinstall both the drivers and the SDK (although the latter shouldn't be necessary).

Answer (score 2):

go to setting-->Application-->Developement-->and check the **USB debugging**

make sure its checked.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy. If you have connected your phone with your computer and as mcnicholls said you need to enable USB debugging. Have a break point some where in your code. And when you Debug as Android Application. It will work. Your break point will be highlighted. And you can debug your program.

Comment: i am not getting the device attached when i go to list command adb devices. Further more, if i run it also, it is running only through emulator..

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have the USB drivers installed for the device you are using.
2. Make sure you see your device's internal storage in My Computer.

Comment: yes george its already been installed. It's for acer e130 which i downloaded and installed from acer website.

Comment: do you see your device storage in My Computer?

Answer (score 1):

To list out how many devices are attached to your machine, run the `adb devices` command:

> paresh@technotalkative:~/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools$ adb devices
>
> List of devices attached

Before starting development, you should make sure below things (As others has also answered):

1. Settings->Applications->Unknown Sources (Make it true)
2. Settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging (Make it true)

Here is a full description which i think you are looking for: [**`Android - Using Hardware Devices`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: it shows nothing below when i issue this command. If i run emulator and list this command, it shows one virtual device. Real device is not been seen.

Comment: check udpates, and which brand's device are you using? Have you installed device driver?